# UItextview selected text not getting deselect when user tap in ios 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, ios11, textselection

I am unable to deselect the selected text in a UITextview (objective c) in ios 11, I have tested in ios 10 and it is working fine. As per my situation when user tap on text view the text get selected(it is working), but when he tries to edit the text and tap on text to deselect at that time it is not getting deselect(only in ios 11),

can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

set textview selectedTextRange property to nil

> self.textView.selectedTextRange = nil;

Comment: in which delegate? because if I do it in didbeginediting then the whole text will not get selected at first time when clicked.